# Databinding to bootstrap table in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, data-binding, pagination

I am working on a web application form.

Currently, I am populating data from database in a grid-view on the button click. I have set the page size to 5 to display 5 rows each time.

[image]

and here is the code of the above pic

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
                    OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      CellPadding="8" AllowPaging="True" 
                      PageSize="5">

                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="SkyBlue" />

                      <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TIMEIN" HeaderText="Time IN" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ORDER_ID" HeaderText="Order ID" />
                        <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="HOST" HeaderText="HOST" />--%>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SOURCE" HeaderText="SOURCE" />

                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" ItemStyle-Width="170px" HeaderText="Request" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval ("REQUEST").ToString ().Substring (0, 80)%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>
```

But instead of using grid-view, I want to make a custom table in bootstrap with fixed number of rows and pagination instead of generating it at run time and then populate data in that table. It should show empty rows if there are less than 5 rows of data. and otherwise, the rest of the rows should appear on next page like that in grid-view.

Something like this

[image]

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover " border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Order ID</th>
                            <th>Time IN</th>
                            <th>Host</th>
                            <th>Source</th>
                            <th>Request</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><button type="button" data-id="1" class="btn btn-default editButton">View</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><button type="button" data-id="2" class="btn btn-default editButton">View</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><button type="button" data-id="3" class="btn btn-default editButton">View</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><button type="button" data-id="4" class="btn btn-default editButton">View</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><button type="button" data-id="5" class="btn btn-default editButton">View</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

How can I bind the data to a custom table? Earlier I was using this to bind the data to a grid-view

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DropDownList1.DataSource = reqSystemData;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "SYSTEM_NAME";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "SYSTEM_NAME";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
```

**reqSystemData** is a type DataTable in which I am fetching data from DB.
How to bind this DataTable to a custom made table with pagination also?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb398790%28v=vs.140%29) which gives you total control over the HTML via Layouts, thus allowing you to apply your [Bootstrap classes](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d560590-a540-45b4-8113-161c5c77535a/listview-responsive-bootstrap?forum=aspwebformsdata) as you wish. [Pagination](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a7450bb5-64dc-4429-81dd-87d9a52ea521/use-bootstrap-pagination-for-aspnet-datapager?forum=aspwebforms) is possible as well. The problem with GridViews is that you have no control over the HTML outputted by the control. This was the motivation for the introduction of ListViews. The code for binding would be no different than that for GridViews.

The biggest challenge with presenting tables in RWD is that you are limited to a 320px viewport with mobile first. This often means displaying only certain columns at this resolution.